# How to generate arcs from attribute data?

Tags: qgis, postgis

What I am trying to achieve is an ellipse-like shape from a digitised point location and cardinal measurements.

For example, point location at 531500,181500 with the attributes North - 4m, South - 6m, East - 5m, West - 5m.

I am guessing the best approach is to calculate the start and end point of 4 arcs in postgis but i'm not sure where to start.